# vue.js 2 how use components in ES2015 webpack

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to use vue-components in a webpack Typescript project but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't get any errors during the build and run, but the component HTML is never inserted into the output - I can just see the HTML source of the component instead i.e. .

My project is an ES2015 using Vue2 in VS.Net 2017. My component looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

// The @Component decorator indicates the class is a Vue component
@Component({
    // All component options are allowed in here
    template: '<button @click="onClick">Click!</button>'
})
export default class MyHeader extends Vue {
    // Initial data can be declared as instance properties
    message: string = 'Hello!'
    // Component methods can be declared as instance methods
    onClick(): void {
        window.alert(this.message)
    }
}
```

I have tried the [official reference guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html) to register the component and use it. When I look at the [vue-component example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/blob/master/example/App.vue), it uses the same format as my project so I added the markup and properties to my Typescript class definition:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import MyHeader from './MyHeader';

@Component({
  components: {
    MyHeader
  }
})
export default class GetDataComponent extends Vue { 
<...rest of class...>
}
```

but in my project the "components:" section is squiggly-underline-red with the message:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'components'
> does not exist in type 'VueClass'. Did you mean to write
> 'component'?

Every example I have seen with vue-component (such as [this one](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/79)) uses the "components:" option in the @Component to register and use their Vue component, but in my project it doesn't seem to like it. I have also tried global registration of the component (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703180/what-is-the-tag-name-of-class-based-vue-component)) which includes the line:

```
// Register the component globally 
Vue.component(my-header', MyHeader)`
```

but in that case I get an error like this:

> Type 'typeof MyHeader' is not assignable to type 'AsyncComponent'

The Vue file works (without the Component added) and all content is rendered correctly. It's getting the Component included that doesn't work - I either get Design-time errors per above, or nothing appears in the output at all.

Is my import wrong? Or the format of the @Component? I get the feeling I am doing something that is very basic, very wrong...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into what appears to be the exact same issue...